# Ways to express popularity

Tags: word-choice, sentence, syntactic-analysis, ordinal-numbers

I'm writing a piece about baby name popularity, and right now in order to express how popular a name was, I'm constantly using sentences in the form of:

> In [year number], Henry was the _th most popular name.

I already have many sentences that look like that, so I need some diversity. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm new, can you tell me why you -1'd this post?

Comment: Hi, user3576467. I didn't downvote or vote to close your post, but the four people who did voted to close it endorsed two canned criticisms: the question is too broad (three people clicked that reason) and you have not included any research with your question (one person clicked that reason). I think the "too broad" criticism is the more serious one: as your question is currently posed, you seem to be asking for suggestions on how to vary the wording "the nth most popular name, which, for this site, is a very open-ended question. As a matter of word choice (rather than grammar or usage)...

Comment: ...lots of options are available once you establish that the cited rankings always refer to name popularity. After you identify the first two or three names as "the nth most popular name," you can start interspersing phrases like "ranked nth in popularity" or "captured nth place" or "finished a distant nth" or "landed a spot in the top XX for popularity at number n." Your task would be a lot easier if you had access to the popularity rankings from one or more previous years, too, so you could throw in remarks about whether a name was gaining ground or slipping in popularity year-to-year.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"sought-after"

```
In [year number], Henry was a notoriously sought-after name.
```

"in vogue"

```
Henry was a name in vogue back in ...
```